# Working with Relationship Attributes. in association NxM rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a relationship between `employee` and `sale` NxM. But in the `employye_sale` table I have the `commission` attribute.
The problem is that! I can not take this `commission` field and show it in the view.

For example:  When registering employee, I can already add a sale in the same view using `rails_admin`. But the commission field is not possible to access.

I'm using the gem `rails_admin`, using `inverse_of` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Where it already does the work of joining the view of `employee` into `sale`. I still can not get a good way to put the relationship attributes

Comment: what your trying?

Comment: I have the following template

table: employee
-id, name, address ...

table: sale
-id, value, product ..

table: employee_sale
-id, sale_id, employee_id, commission
................
I wanted to put a value of 'commission' at the moment that user is to register a sale and adduce an employee.                              .

As rails_admin already does the job of adding a employee modal for sale.
I would like to append these fields from the employye_sale table